# Do I have all the javascript files I need?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, gmaps4rails

I'm running a rails 3 app, and have just installed gmaps4rails.  Everything works great in my development environment, but when I move it over to production no map is showing.
In my production log, there isn't any error.
In my javascript console I'm getting:

```
Result of expression 'google.maps' [undefined] is not an object.
```

Do you have any ideas on how to get this to work?

Comment: Do you get any errors in Firebug's "Network" tab? About script files that failed to load?

Comment: please list js files included in your page + their order

Answer (score 1):

You don't have the required CSS and JS in production env likely.
Add this to production.rb

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

in development you run ‘rails generate gmaps4rails:install’ to copy the JS and CSS assets to your /public folder.